# How can I migrate product images to Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, migration, magento2-migration-tool

How can I migrate the images of my products from Magento 1 to my Magento 2?

I'll use the official migration tool of the Magento.

Thanks

Comment: What's your problem with the official documentation?

Comment: There' s nothing about the images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All media files (images for products, categories, the WYSIWYG editor, and so on) should be copied manually from your Magento 1 install `media` folder to your Magento 2 install `pub/media` folder.

> However, do not copy the **.htaccess** files located in the Magento 1 media folder. Magento 2 has its own **.htaccess** that should be preserved.

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-manually.html

Comment: Can you confirm this works after migrate catalog data using the oficial data migration tool?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at the official documentation, and it says that you can't do it - sorry :)

Look here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-manually.html

Answer (score -2):

**Firstly**, you need to **create and develop a fresh new site** on Magento 2 (including theme implementation, module installation, shipping and payment integration, languages and currencies configuration, and so on)

**Secondly**, you can migrate directly all your data including products, orders, customers, extensions, especially images of your products... from your store on Magento 1 to Magento 2. If you are a tech-guru, you should do it manually, it saves you a lot of money. If you are not, you should find an automated migration tool or Magento migration experts to help you to perform the Magento migration successfully.